# Orientacion de pantalla web

Tags: css

Tengo una duda espero me puedan ayudar. Tengo un media query para una resolucion movil pero quiero restringir la orientacioón horizontal, alguien sabe como se puede hacer eso.

Comment: Hola obed, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Después, busca en el sitio a ver si ya está la respuesta (creo que deberia existir) y sino, muestranos lo que has investigado e intentado para que podamos ayudarte sobre tu problema concreto. Mira [ask] y [mcve] para  más info. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

La sintaxis es:

```
@media all and (orientation: portrait|landscape) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes probar de esta forma

> @media only screen and (orientation:portrait){    }
>
> @media only screen and (orientation:landscape){  }

y también lo puedes intentar con JavaScript:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  function reorient(e) {
    var portrait = (window.orientation % 180 == 0);
    $("body > div").css("-webkit-transform", !portrait ? "rotate(-90deg)" : "");
  }
  window.onorientationchange = reorient;
  window.setTimeout(reorient, 0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Con **CSS** no puedes restringir o evitar que rote el dispositivo, pero puedes crear un **CSS** para cuando este horizontal la pantalla `orientation:landscape` ó vertical `orientation:portrait`; para activar cuando se usa uno u otro en tu **HTML** donde haces referencia a tu archivo **CSS** puedes indicar con el atributo **media** cuando se usa uno y cuando se usa otro, ejemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Titulo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../portrait.css" media="only screen and (orientation:portrait)">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../landscape.css" media="only screen and (orientation:landscape)">
</head>
```

Como veras hay dos referencias en el **HTML** a dos archivos **CSS**, uno llamado `portrait.css` y el otro `landscape.css`, y en dichas referencias hay un atributo `media` con el valor `only` el cual indica que solo se usara si y solo si pasa lo siguiente: `screen and (orientation:portrait|landscape)`. Al decir esto estas diciendo que se ejecutara ese **CSS** cuando la pantalla tenga una orientación horizontal ó vertical.

Ahora si tienes un archivo **CSS** puedes también hacer dicha regla en ese archivo así:

```
@media only screen and (orientation:portrait) {
  border:1px solid red;
}

@media only screen and (orientation:landscape) {
  border:1px solid blue;
}
```

Con esto puedes dividir el comportamiento del **CSS** según la orientación de tu dispositivo.